# xml schema collection change - huge performance hit

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, performance, t-sql

I'm seeing a huge performance hit in our enterprise application when changing the XML schema collection of a given column on a large table. Simplistically put, we're doing something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE HugeTable ALTER COLUMN CustomFields XML
```

(note: CustomFields was previously bound to XML(CustomFieldsSchemaCollection, but of course we need to modify that xml schema, so we need this statement so that that schema can be modified)

And then, after modifying the CustomFieldSchemaCollection, we do this:

```
ALTER TABLE HugeTable ALTER COLUMN CustomFields XML(CustomFieldSchemaCollection)
```

The first statement takes 8 minutes and the second statement takes 10 minutes.

We found we could slightly optimize the first statement (50% performance boost) by using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE HugeTable ALTER COLUMN CustomFields nvarchar(max)
```

The effect is that the first statement takes 4 minutes and the second statement takes 10 (so, 14 min, down from 18).

**Bottom line question is...**
Is there a way to do this "xml schema re-binding" (or whatever one calls it) in a way that avoids SQL Server's totally unnecessary and redundant checking of every value in the column? 
(Note: yes, we can safely assume that the existing XML data in that table will conform to the new xml schema collection.)

Thanks to anyone who can assist!

Comment: if this is a one time change, what is the big deal with it taking 15-20 minutes?

Comment: KM: great question! this is part of the upgrade process. unfortunately, on even semi-large databases it's taking a long time--hours--and leading to failed upgrades (timeout errors). As a company, we are trying to move away from the "just increase the timeout threshold" solution, since that's bitten us in the past way too much.

Answer (score 0):

If time really is a big issue (which on a 1 time upgrade shouldn't really matter much) could you consider just removing the underlying data, do your re-binding to the new schema, then do a bulk insert turning all the identity insert issues off etc...?

Or for a super stepwise, write a script that does the following as batches:

1. Alter the table and add a new XML column with the new schema
   binding
2. Set the new column data = new old column data
3. Drop the old column.
4. Rename the new column to the old column name.
5. Modify Ordinality if needed (Different Topic... And unless all your consuming queries are written 
   safely by specifying column names instead of relying on the
   underlying ordinality)